# Changing value of SELECT via jQuery not triggering AJAX for next field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get it so that when I click onto a link, it'll change the value of a select field. There is JS (outlined below) in place to enable the next select field once the first has been selected. This appears to be triggered by 'onChange' so I thought my code would work. It does change the value in the first select field, but the AJAX to enable the second select and grab it's values is not triggered unless I manually select the value from the first select and click it with my mouse.

The code for changing the value of the select on-click is...

```
$('.dropdown-element li').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#finder-3--16').val(value).trigger('change');
    return false;
});
```

The code that I'm trying to trigger essentially is below...

```
initialize: function(containerId, ajaxUrl, loadingText, isNeedLast)
{
    this.containerId = containerId;
    this.ajaxUrl     = ajaxUrl;
    this.loadingText = loadingText;
    this.isNeedLast  = Number(isNeedLast);
    this.selects     = new Array();

    //possible bug if select order in the HTML will be different
    $$('#' + this.containerId + ' select').each(function(select){
        select.observe('change', this.onChange.bindAsEventListener(this));
        this.selects[this.selects.length] = select;
    }.bind(this));
},

onChange: function(event)
{
    var select     = Event.element(event);
    var parentId   = select.value;
    var dropdownId = 0;

    /* should load next element's options only if current is not the last one */
    for (var i = 0; i < this.selects.length; i++){
        if (this.selects[i].id == select.id && i != this.selects.length-1){
            var selectToReload = this.selects[i + 1];
            if (selectToReload){
                dropdownId = selectToReload.id.substr(selectToReload.id.search('--') + 2);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Any and all help is much appreciated as I'm stumped! Thanks!

Comment: after the line that says "possible bug" why do you have `$$('#'...` instead of `$('#'...`?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed it but it didn't fix my issue unfortunately. Thanks!